# C++ concat name of constant and variable

Tags: c++, c, macros, constants, concatenation

My code is following:

```
#define TEXT_EN "English"
#define TEXT_PL "Polish"
```

I have variable which determines text language (char *lang = "_PL" or lang = "_EN"), so I want to display correct text in my macros DISPLAY_TEXT(text).

Is it possible to concatenate the name of constant and above variable to obtain correct constant? For example:

```
DISPLAY_TEXT(TEXT ## lang)
```

Comment: You can't combine runtime variables with preprocessor or other compile-time computations.
You can define a LANG as _EN or _PL then use TEXT##LANG... I think. I don't use the preprocessor much.

Comment: It's not solution for me, because lang has to be variable, because I want to change it after compilation and store it to the EEPROM memory.

Comment: Then use runtime solution to get the current language string, such as a map to a string with a "language enum" as key.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not.

Either you have both strings available at compile time and then you can concatenate them using `##`, or you have one or more strings available only in run time and then you have to use `strcpy`/`strcat`, for example.